# Node.js Promises Run Without Being Called

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

When using promises, they run automatically without being called. I followed the MDN Docs on setting them up, and they run when they are declared, without being prompted.

```js
var progressPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  // Query the DB to receive the ToDo tasks
  // inProgress is the tableID

  getTasks(inProgress, function(tasks) {
    // Check that the list is returned.
    console.log("Shouldn't Run Automatically");
    if (tasks) {
      console.log("This Too Runs Automatically");
      resolve(tasks);
    } else {
      reject("There was a failure, the data was not received");
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<p>Console Output</p>
<p> Shouldn't Run Automatically </p>
<p> This too runs automatically </p>
```

I've checked the remaining code, only the promises trigger when I start the app with `node index.js`

Is this by design, or is my implementation wrong? If it's by design it would be great if you could link me to the docs, because I was unable to find anything on it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ...and they run when they are declared, without being prompted

You don't "declare" promises. `new Promise` creates a promise and calls the executor function you pass it, *synchronously*, before `new Promise` returns. You do that when you want the work the executor does to be started (right then), not later.

If you want to define something that will do something returning a promise but not start it yet, simply put it in a function:

```
// Explicit promise creation (only when necessary)
function doProgress() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // ...
    });
}

// Or an `async` function, which always returns a promise
async function doProgress() {
    // ...code using `await` on other promises/thenables here...
}
```

...then call it when you want that process to begin:

```
var progressPromise = doProgress();
```

Documentation:

- [*Using Promises* on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)
- [`Promise` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [*Promise Objects* in the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-objects)

Comment: FWIW, I also go into promises in depth in Chapter 8 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys* (and `async` functions and `await` in Chapter 9). Links in my profile if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

you can use promise like this in js

```
async function asyncfunc() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        yourFuncWithCallBack((data) => {
            if (data) {
                resolve(data)
            }
            reject(new Error('data did not exist'))
        });
    });
}
```

and use asyncFunction like this

```
try {
   var data = await asyncfunc();
   // do some thing with data
} catch (error) {
 // do some thing with error
}
```

if you want to use promise in typescript

```
interface ResolveDataType {
   // some property
}

async function asyncfunc():Promise<ResolveDataType> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        yourFuncWithCallBack((data:ResolveDataType) => {
            if (data) {
                resolve(data)
            }
            reject(new Error('data did not exist'))
        });
    });
}
```

and use asyncFunc like this

```
try {
   const data = await asyncfunc();
   // do some thing with data
} catch (error) {
 // do some thing with error
}
```